# Determine c so hypothesis test has level of significance α= 0.05

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have the solution but can't find an explanation that makes sense to me so I'm hoping someone here can explain it to me.

**Question:**
Consider a sample with just one observation $X$ that is assumed to have a probability density function $f_X$ that depends on an unknown parameter $\theta\in\{0, 1\}$. The density $f_X$ is given by:

For $\theta=0$:

$$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
      2x & \text{for 0 < $x$ < 1,}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases} 
$$

For $\theta=1$:

$$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
      3x^2 & \text{for 0 < $x$ < 1,}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases} 
$$

Consider the following two hypotheses:

$H_0: \theta = 0 \\
H_1: \theta = 1$

We are interested in using the following test: Accept $H_0$ if $X \leq c$ where $c>0$ is a constant.

**Determine $c$ so the above test has level of significance $\alpha = 0.05$.**

I know the answer is $c = 0.9746$ but I don't understand why. My textbook doesn't seem to have any examples that are like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\alpha&=P(X>c|\theta=0)\\
&=1-\frac12\cdot c\cdot2c\\
&=1-c^2.
\end{align}
$$
Now if $\alpha=0.05$ we have $c=\sqrt{0.95}$.

Comment: How do you get from $P(X>c|θ=0)$ to $1-\frac{1}{2} \cdot c \cdot 2c$?

Comment: Geometrically: just draw a picture ...